# PIG: Filter a string on a basis of a phrase

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I was wondering if it is possible yo filter a string on the basis of the phrase? For example,I want to count number of times when ps3(ps 3) appears in the query. I am not sure how not to use exact match with the filter condition for "ps 3" as do not know how to put a tab inside of it. My code so far is:

```
data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/' using PigStorage(',') as (text:chararray);
filtered_data = FILTER data BY (text matches '.*ps3.*') OR (text == 'ps 3');
Res = FOREACH (GROUP filtered_data ALL) GENERATE COUNT(filtered_data);
DUMP Res;
```

So obviously code fails to count queries like "ps 3 today". Is there is a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage(',')  AS  (text:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (LOWER(text) MATCHES '.*ps 3.*' OR LOWER(text) MATCHES '.*ps3.*');
```

**DUMP B Output :**

```
(ps 3 today)
(ps 3)
(ps3)
(PS3TODAY)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I have tried this schema and for some reason it was not working. Need to brew myself more coffee though!